# How do you get Sidecar scrolling working?

Tags: sidecar

I've got a MBP 16 attached to an iPad (6th generation). The official Apple support page (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210380) mentions two finger swiping to scroll, but it's not working for me. Has anyone else gotten two finger scrolling working on their Sidecar?

Comment: Yes, it works as described.  If it's not working for you, and you have followed the stated requirements, then we'll need more info to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @fsb what additional info is needed to troubleshoot? I noticed the sidecar touchbar buttons also don't work.

Comment: Verify you have supported hardware and software. Steps you took to set it up. What you've already done to troubleshoot. Stuff like that.

Comment: Hardware and software are supported. 2020 MBP with 6th gen iPad, both on the latest software updates. I set it up by taking the steps at the top of the link in the OP. The iPad sidecar works as a display, but doesn't accept any input. I've Googled my issue as well as 'sidecar troubleshooting' but I didn't find anyone else experiencing my particular issue.